# How to filter the git log with only the commit date yyyyddmm format and commit message which has the release of last three months?

Tags: git, git-log

I want the output of git log as below -

"2022-06-02 Release Point "

Release Point is what we put into the commit message.

So far, I have tried below commands, I am having trouble in the displayed date format and get only the commit message.

git log --pretty=format:"%ad - %an: %s" --after="2022-09-08" --until="2022-11-18" --grep="Build Integration Point"

It gives me below output -

Fri Nov 11 16:38:05 2022 +0100 - Author Name: -------------------- Release Commit message --------------------

I only want the date and the Release commit message. I want all other details excluded from my output.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble in the displayed date

```
%ad
author date (format respects --date= option)
```

i.e. if you want another format: describe it with additional option `--date` for log

> get only the commit message

don't use not needed placeholders in format string, namely `%an`

```
%an
author name
```